# Could preg_match be the only line of defense?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, defensive-programming

I was wondering that, if preg_match() could be used as the only line of defense on PHP.

Testing preg_match(), at least for a simple input form field, it accepts only what's acceptable by regex and returns false for everything else:

For numbers:

```
function GetUserID($userid) {
   $regexnum = "/^[0-9]+$/";
   if(preg_match($regexnum, $userid) != 1 OR empty($userid)) {
      return false;
   }
   else {
      return $userid;
   }
}
```

For names:

```
function GetUsername ($user) {
   $regex = "/^[a-zA-Zà-ûÀ-ÛçÇ\s]+$/";
   if (preg_match($regex, $user) != 1 OR empty($user)) {
      return false;
   }
   else {
      return $user;
   }
}
```

So my question is, can preg_match() be the only line of defense without using htmlentities() or filter_var() as it doesn't accept anything alse or am I missing something?

*** Edit ***
I've created this code to test it:
[Test Site](http://www.ibtaproject.hol.es/regextest.php)

Comment: Depends on what you're doing. If you're taking real names you'd need to accept `'` and some other non-alpha characters, at which point, if used in a certain order, SQL injection could be possible. **Kids, always use proper protection!** :p

Comment: @SmokeyPHP In Brazil we don't use `'` so on my code it accepts the common characters `á,é,ç` and some others that might come. And if there is some uncommon char the person might know that his/her name is unusual. The code on `edit` checks some random characters and didn't accept malicious code.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP but that's a good idea to think about inserting `'` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. *However* it's a good idea to not rely on it exclusively, because a slight change to the regex could make you vulnerable. Using the proper escaping function is ideal because even if your validation code changes, your sanitisation code will not.

Comment: Do you mean the change of `$regex`? Would that be changed only by me or by someone else with XSS or similar?

Comment: You might change it if you decide you want to allow apostrophes. Or another developer might do it if someone else works on your project.